# error at run time from cx-freeze when use matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, cx-freeze

I started with using cx-freeze with the source file contain only `print("hello from cx-freeze")`. It worked just fine.

Then, I tried https://gist.github.com/joferkington/9214844 I got the error message. I change my source file to be very simple. I still get TCL_LIBRARY error. I followed suggestion from [KeyError: 'TCL_Library' when I use cx_Freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533803/keyerror-tcl-library-when-i-use-cx-freeze) (Martin Tournoij)

The error is gone. The exe files are created (like 500+ mb). When I run the file, I get the error message.

I check other people question
[Creating exe file with cx_Freeze, PyQt4, matplotlib and multiple .py files does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720066/creating-exe-file-with-cx-freeze-pyqt4-matplotlib-and-multiple-py-files-does)
(no answer provided there)

other questions like [cx_Freeze help. ImportError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093417/cx-freeze-help-importerror)

[cx-freeze fails to include modules even when included specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205219/cx-freeze-fails-to-include-modules-even-when-included-specifically)
or
[cx-freeze doesn't find all dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486292/cx-freeze-doesnt-find-all-dependencies)

I checked them, but does not seem to apply to my case (at least I don't know how to make it work with what I am doing, if you can please explain more thank you)

This one is similar
[ImportError: No module named 'queue' while running my app freezed with cx_freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768570/importerror-no-module-named-queue-while-running-my-app-freezed-with-cx-freeze)
but the solution was to import multiprocessing (I also tried that too it does not work)

I tried the full option for the setup.py

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import os.path
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

base = 'Console'

options = {
    'build_exe': {'packages': ["pandas","numpy","scipy","matplotlib"],
        'include_files':[
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'Library', 'plugins', 'platforms')
         ],
    },
}

executables = [
    Executable('plot2.py', base = base)
]

setup(name = "plot2" ,
      version = "0.1" ,
      description = "" ,
      executables = executables,
      options = options
      )
```

I also try less option

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import os.path
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

base = 'Console'

options = {
    'build_exe': {'packages': ["matplotlib"],
        'include_files':[
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll')]
    }
}

executables = [
    Executable('plot2.py', base = base)
]

setup(name = "plot2" ,
      version = "0.1" ,
      description = "" ,
      executables = executables,
      options = options
      )
```

Both are fine. I even have `tcl86t.dll` and `tk86t.dll` in my target folder.
Yet both fail when I try to run it. The setup with "less option" give the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__start
up__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console
.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "plot2.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line
 127, in <module>
    from . import cbook
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py"
, line 35, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 158,
 in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 1
3, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line
8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", lin
e 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line
 38, in <module>
    from . import numeric
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line
2896, in <module>
    from . import fromnumeric
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", l
ine 15, in <module>
    from . import _methods
ImportError: cannot import name '_methods'
```

Even with https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/blob/master/cx_Freeze/samples/matplotlib/setup.py

```
base = 'Console'
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'
```

It still does not work (`python setup.py build` work, but the program does not run when I double click `.exe` file).

My code of plot2.py is just reduced to creating jpg file (it run when I did just `python plot2.py`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,4,5.5]
y = [3,4,5,6,7.7]
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y,'o')
plt.savefig("test.jpg",dpi = 200)
```

I install python via anaconda. `python --version` gives

```
Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

result. `conda list` show that my `cx-Freeze` version is 5.1.1

with

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'
```

and add multiprocessor in the packages list it does not work (I think it is not relevant but see other people did (on other application) and it work so I tried, probably wrong). The best I can do is getting this error (picture below) at run time.

[error report when click on the exe file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5arC2.jpg)

Is there a way to fix this? I have python on ubuntu system too, but did not try yet. I can uninstall python or use other version of python/cx-Freeze if this help. If I need to install other version of python/cx-Freeze please tell me how to do it, too.

Another question here is that is there a way to make the exe file that is smaller. Just create a graph should not be 500+ mb program. Maybe I include the package/file that should be excluded. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, what worked was that I used 'pyinstaller' instead of 'cx_freeze' and then after building the exe file, I copied the 'platforms' folder from "c:\Users\\envs\environmentname>\Library\plugins\platforms" to where the main .exe file was.